# LinkedIn doesn't get (fetch) post image #linkedin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, linkedin-api

**Problem:**
LinkedIn doesn't fetch the post image on this website: https://anon.to/A4rTki but it does fetch the other meta data.

**Undertaken actions by me:**

- Disable all plugins + remove all browser history. > Doesn't work.
- The above + test it in other browsers and mobile phone. > Doesn't
  work.
- The above + paste a direct link into LinkedIn status update on the
  LinkedIn website itself. It shows everything except the post image. > Doesn't work.

**What works (but no real solution):**
If I install an exact copy of the website on another domain everything works.

**My ideas about the problem:**

- I recently switched to https, could this be the problem?
- I examined the code on the website when I click "deel" (share button) and I
  see **LinkedIn does get the post image, but the image does not work on
  the link LinkedIn creates by itself to host the image on their own
  CDN.**

***What can I do to fix this?***

Thanks for the help!

In the image below you see LinkedIn does get post the images, but does not show them.
[image]

## linkedin

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! It is the **Let's Encrypt SSL** certificate. If I remove it and share the page, LinkedIn sees the image again!

Some WordPress.com websites also don't work because of Let's Encrypt SSL with LinkedIn share.